# JAVA:¿como hacer consultas de una palabra dentro de un RandomAccessFile?

Tags: java, archivo, sql

bueno es mi primera pregunta aqui:
tengo duda en como hacer una consulta dentro de un randomaccessfile.
tengo esta parte del codigo lo unico que hace es que si le escribo el nombre de mi primer producto que se encuentra en la lista si lo imprime, pero si busco otro nombre que se encuentre mas adelante que me dice que el" producto no se encuentra registrado" aunque lo este.

```
public void Consulta() 
{
    try
    {
        Prod=new RandomAccessFile(Catalogo.dat,rw);

        String Pro,busc;
        int Encontrado=0;
        busc=JOptionPane.showInputDialog(ingressa el nombre del producto);
        while((Pro=Prod.readLine())!=null)
        {
            if(Pro.equalsIgnoreCase(busc))
            {
                Familia=Prod.readLine();
                Marca=Prod.readLine();
                Bod=Prod.readLine();
                Precio=Prod.readFloat();

                System.out.println(nombre+Pro+n 
                        + Familia+Familia+n
                        + Marca+Marca+n
                        + Bodega+Bod+n
                        + Precio$+Precio+n);
                Encontrado++;
            }
        }
        if(Encontrado==0)
        {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, el Producto no esta registrado);
        }
        Prod.close();
    }
    catch(FileNotFoundException e)
    {

    }
    catch(IOException e)
    {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

deberias utilizar la funcion del string contains(busc) envez de

> equalsIgnoreCase(busc)